# Bootstrap 3 Textarea with input-group-button and btn-group-vertical

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3, I have a form with a textarea and two buttons. What I want is group the buttons with btn-group-vertical and textarea with the buttons with input-group-button.

My code is it:

```
<form>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" style="resize:none"></textarea>
        <span type="submit" class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">Button 1</span>
        <span type="submit" class="input-group-addon btn btn-primary">Button 2</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

This option the buttons stays so big.

Second option:

```
<form>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" style="resize:none"></textarea>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="btn-group-vertical">
                <span type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Button 1</span>
                <span type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Button 2</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

I would like something like the second option but without the grey box and this margin.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Its your use of span, it will take up as much room as there is left, it's like a fill.  You can use a grid to trap things were you want them.  Do you know how to implement row/col definition in bootstrap, implement the grid?

Comment: yes, I do, but I don't understand where I use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file Write

```
.input-group-addon{
  padding: 0;
}
```

and that will remove the padding around the buttons.

Comment: its not working. It remove padding left and right, but top and botton doesn't change.

Comment: thanks, but if I change height or rows of textarea, this breaks